# How does an identicon identify a user?

Tags: discussion, identicon

[This page](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/01/22/Identicons_as_Visual_Fingerprints.aspx) says that Identicons are generated on the basis of hash of the user's IP address.

But, what happens if I change my IP address (for example - log in fro a different machine)?

Comment: Given the "identify" in the question: a comment from Kyle at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35222/include-email-address-hash-in-the-data-dump-files: *This guy has had some success gleaning email addresses from Stack Overflow based on the Gravatar hash: http://www.developer.it/post/gravatars-why-publishing-your-email-s-hash-is-not-a-good-idea (summary: 8597 addresses, or ~10% of those scraped).*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Then you get a different icon.

*Unless* you provide an email. In which case the icon is based on a [hash of your email](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/url).

Comment: `icon is based on a hash of your "email"`, is it?

Comment: Yes it is. ----

Comment: The default is based on your e-mail's hash, but you have the option of setting your own avatar images, and with the help an [identicon generator](http://finalboss.org/g/?hash=Stack+Overflow) out of many freely available, you can set up your SO's identicon to pretty much any text. --- Trivia: [Some very interesting results can be achieved](http://finalboss.org/g/?hash=Link+%26+Zelda).

Comment: So would it technically be possible to translate the image back to an md5, un-hash the md5, and retrieve a user's email address?

Comment: @MDXF - Yes, and it had been done with some success. Look at the comment to the question. The icon's URL already contains the hash, so you don't have to deal with the image at all.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship between identicon/Gravatar and email address was clarified for me in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37096/who-or-what-is-this-so-user).

In particular, how come so many 'different' users had the same identicon?

Comment: The question is not available currently. It shows ***Page Not Found***.