# Why are the profileimageurl in the data dump of almost all Stack Exchange websites blank?

Tags: support, data-dump, profile-picture

I wonder why the profileimageurl in the data dump of almost all Stack Exchange websites are blank.

Comment: Why so many downvotes? It's important to check the dump.

Answer (score 10):

As best I can tell, this was a part of the security improvements with [We're regenerating all Gravatar identicons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389123/323179). I was using queries that used that field months before that post and noticed that the field was empty a while after that.

Similarly, there is also an email hash field which was made blank for security reasons well before my time.

Comment: You're correct. Gravatar identicons were removed from the data dump intentionally as part of that work.