# Network profile still shows original identicon

Tags: bug, status-review, network-profile, identicon

According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389123/were-regenerating-all-gravatar-identicons), all identicons have been regenerated. However, on the Network Profile page it still has the original identicon.

Compare [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/390967/alex) and [here](https://stackexchange.com/users/9279508/alex). In the former you can see my new dark blue identicon, while the latter still has my original light blue identicon.

[image: Screenshot of Meta Stack Exchange profile showing new identicon]

[image: Screenshot of Network Profile showing original identicon]

Comment: I noticed this too, but with a bit of a special case. Staff member [tanj92](https://stackexchange.com/users/24750240/tanj92) has the "[default](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379303/323179)" identicon still for the network profile icon, but all the site profiles have a dog picture. (Most or all of the other users linked in that post do have a new network profile icon.)

Comment: That's because network profile is not synched.